# HTML5, Video and Javascript: using video timeline to control page behavior

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having the following problem: i have to show a video inside a page, but it needs to alternate with page content. Everytime the video stops playing, i have to show a div or something. After a few seconds, that div goes away and the video starts playing again. Alternating between normal content and video.

Is this possible with HTML5 and JS? Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Consider implementing [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/). It's part of Mozilla's Popcorn project.

The demo on the front page shows a div with changing HTML content depending on the time code of the video.

> Popcorn.js is an HTML5 media framework written in JavaScript for filmmakers, web developers, and anyone who wants to create time-based interactive media on the web

Answer (score 0):

Bind an event when the video stops (`addEventListener( "ended", function(){ ... }, false)`) to show the div, start a timer after which the div hides and video starts playing again.